# Add audio stream to html audio element with javascript audio API

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to add audio stream to html audio element with javascript audio API. the code below works perfectly with a source file on the server, but it will NOT add a stream. Starting a stream with html5 audio at html level works fine, but the rest of the snippet will not work. this is my javascript and html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style>
div#mp3_player{ width:500px; height:90px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; }
div#mp3_player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;  }
div#mp3_player > canvas{ width:500px; height:60px; background:#002D3C; float:left; }
</style>
<script>
// Create a new instance of an audio object and adjust some of its properties
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'Five Finger Death Punch - Wrong Side Side of Heaven HD.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
    context = new webkitAudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
    analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper(){
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // Color of the bars
    bars = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
        //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mp3_player">
  <div id="audio_box"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is..... a file on the server works fine.... but a stream will not play. It appears to load, but i have no sound from the stream. 
a demo of it working with a sorce file is at [enter link description here](http://x-webb.design/radio.php)

the stream i am trying to play is http://173.35.234.36:8000/stream

TY for any help that may b offered :)

Comment: http://173.35.234.36:8000/stream  The file you requested could not be found

Comment: @monkey the link works fine for me

Comment: the link works fine.... it is online at http://autodude666.com/network ..... and @Patrick Roberts.. TYVM.. i will look into it.

Comment: @JamesWalker I just tested your code by running it in the console on my demo site and it works fine. Just out of curiosity, why are you setting the `src` to `Five Finger Death Punch - Wrong Side Side of Heaven HD.mp3` when you say you're requesting `http://173.35.234.36:8000/stream`? Also if it's a cross-domain request, the remote server needs to support CORS in order for the web audio API to work.

Comment: Hey @PatrickRoberts . The sound file is on my hosting, beside the php file... same domain. I tried to read the CORS link.. i am not getting anywhere with it. nothing is connecting. Cant figure out where to put the code. The article seems to be written for Pro's . i am only a intermediate novice. the stream is being sent from a streaming server from my home machine. I understand the concept... hosting sends a request to my local server, and my local server sends the stream. thats as far as i got. is there any more literature on this subject? I cold find none... maybe searching with wrong words.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your server hosting the stream is PHP? If so, take a look at this: http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: lol.. Yes i saw that. I do not know what language the icecsast2 server is in. I am running out of time, and i KNOW the stream works directly into HTML5 audio element with no problems... so i guess i am going to have to code my page without the fancy spectrum analizer bar untill a later date. But... i do thank you very much for trying to set me off in the right direction. @PatrickRoberts :)

Comment: @JamesWalker http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#global-headers Here's how to set HTTP headers in Icecast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, your endpoint, [`http://173.35.234.36:8000/stream`](http://173.35.234.36:8000/stream), does not support [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/). When requesting it from a different origin (i.e. different domain, port or protocol), the request will be denied by the browser for the following reason:

> MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for http://173.35.234.36:8000/stream